# how can i store an image in dynamodb using python?

Tags: python, image, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to put an image in a table created in dynamodb. The table has only one column called `name`, in which the names of the images are getting stored.

I cannot find a way to edit the table to incorporate another column to store the image, nor can I find a way to put the image in dynamodb table.

I am using python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With you table structure you can store the name of the image, that's it, no additional data. In most cases a single column database table it less useful than others.

Comment: When i am creating a table from aws i do not get a chance to create any other column..not do i get to add columns later...how do put a picture in aws dynamodb table?

Comment: I guess you have to dive into no sql database and dynamodb. The concept is very different from traditional database. The starting point us the documentation provided by Amazon.

Comment: i have been reading through the documentation ..but they did not provide me with any help...any idea where should i look into?..most importantly can image even be stored on dynamodb??any help appretiated

Answer (score 1):

The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400KB. DynamoDB is not the right solution if you want to store images bigger than 400KB. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items

What you can do is store the image in S3 and save the corresponding S3 key name in DynamoDB. Save the S3 key name as a new attribute in your DynamoDB table for S3 key name.

DynamoDB is schema less and you can add additional attributes on the go. Give it a try in AWS console.

Also look at this doc for DynamoDB best practices
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html

Comment: Hi, when i am trying to put an image tinto a dynamodb table on the fly i get the following error : "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte"...what i basically want to do is store an image as an object in the dynamodb

Comment: ok finaaly my solution : i stored the images in aws s3 and stored the link of the same in dynamodb.this link on accessing does serve me with the picture from s3.